# How do I subtract two dates in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, datetime, date, time

I'm working on a little fitness tracker in order to teach myself Django. I want to graph my weight over time, so I've decided to use the Python Google Charts Wrapper. Google charts require that you convert your date into a x coordinate. To do this I want to take the number of days in my dataset by subtracting the first weigh-in from the last weigh-in and then using that to figure out the x coords (for example, I could 100 by the result and increment the x coord by the resulting number for each y coord.)

Anyway, I need to figure out how to subtract Django datetime objects from one another and so far, I am striking out on both google and here at the stack. I know PHP, but have never gotten a handle on OO programming, so please excuse my ignorance. Here is what my models look like:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    goal_weight = models.DecimalField("Goal Weight", 
        max_digits=4, 
        decimal_places=1)
    target_date = models.DateTimeField("Target Date to Reach Goal")
    set_date = models.DateTimeField("When did you set your goal?")
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.goal_weight)

class Weight(models.Model):
    """ Weight at a given date and time. """

    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal)
    weight = models.DecimalField("Current Weight",
        max_digits=4, 
        decimal_places=1)
    weigh_date = models.DateTimeField("Date of Weigh-In")
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.weight)

    def recorded_today(self):
        return self.date.date() == datetime.date.today()
```

Any ideas on how to proceed in the view? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can just subtract the dates directly, which will yield a `datetime.timedelta` object:

```
dt = weight_now.weight_date - weight_then.weight_date
```

A `timedelta` object has fields for days, seconds, and microseconds. From there, you can just do the appropriate math. For example:

```
hours = dt.seconds / 60 / 60    # Returns number of hours between dates
weeks = dt.days / 7             # number of weeks between dates
```

Answer (score 37):

Django `datetime` objects are just regular [Python `datetime` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#datetime-objects).  When you subtract one `datetime` from another you get a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#timedelta-objects) object.

If you are looking to subtract a length of time from a `datetime` you need to subtract a `timedelta` object from it.  For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> print now
2010-05-18 23:16:24.770533
>>> this_time_yesterday = now - timedelta(hours=24)
>>> print this_time_yesterday
2010-05-17 23:16:24.770533
>>> (now - this_time_yesterday).days
1
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much... I'm so used to thinking in strings, I didn't think can object could be generated by subtracting two other objects.

Answer (score 5):

Note that subtracting will not work in case the two date times have different offset-awareness, e.g., one with tzinfo and one without (native).

Comment: this is not an answer to the question.  leave a comment on another answer if you have something to add to what's been said