# How to subtract current date with date from database

Tags: python, mysql, django, date, subtraction

I have a Donor table with `lastAttendance` column. How can I subtract current day with selected lastAttendance date?

```
d0 = Donor.objects.only("lastAttendance")
d1 = datetime.now()
delta = d1 - d0
```

Error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'QuerySet'
```

Comment: d0 is a queryset, ie a container of all your Donor objects with their lastAttendance fields. Which one do you want to calculate the date for?

Comment: today  - lastAttendance (difference between days)

Comment: How did that in any way answer my question? You have *multiple* Donor objects, each with their own lastAttendance value. Which do you want to calculate?

Comment: i wanna calculate for all of them

Comment: Then iterate query resultset and calculate in for-each.

Comment: Isnt that a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861770/how-do-i-subtract-two-dates-in-django-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timesince function for Django. Read about it in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
from django.utils import timezone  
d0 = Donor.objects.only("lastAttendance")[0]
d1 = timezone.now()
delta = d1 - d0.lastAttendance
```

Comment: still the same error:
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'QuerySet'

Comment: @kasia `Donor.objects.only("lastAttendance")` returns a queryset. In order to get results, you should iterate through the list. Also please note the update.

Comment: @kasia: If you want to iterate the difference in a template, you can iterate through the objects, then store the difference in a list. In the template, you can use a for loop to display the values.