# How to subtract two date and get the number of days in annotate?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm making a query to get the number of days from the date that a person bought a new phone until today.

```
device_record = Devc.objects.annotate(duration = todays_date - F('datebuy'))\
    .order_by('datebuy')
```

When I retrieve the data, i got this `3150 days, 20:08:00` .

How can I do to remove the time because I just want to display the `number of days`?

I've tried:

```
device_record = Devc.objects.annotate(duration = (todays_date - F('datebuy')).days)\
        .order_by('datebuy')
```

the error returned: 
`'F' object has no attribute 'days'`

I define todays_date like this `todays_date = datetime.now().date()`, the `datebuy` is `DateTimeField`

Comment: What is the type of todays_date? 
Maybe this is helpful [subtrack two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861770/how-do-i-subtract-two-dates-in-django-python?rq=1)

Comment: I define todays_date like this `todays_date = datetime.now().date()`, the `datebuy` is `DateTimeField`

Comment: @Samantha Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to subtract the timestamps and then retrieve the days.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
yesterday =  now - timedelta(days=1)
duration = now - yesterday

print duration.days
```

**Output:**

1

Answer (score 1):

```
device_record = Devc.objects.annotate(duration = todays_date - F('datebuy')).order_by('datebuy')

device_record = device_record.annotate(duration_in_days = F('duration__day'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a number of days a user buy a phone. You can query like this
`device_record = Devc.objects.order_by('datebuy')`

Then in template
`{{ your_date_field|timesince:current_date_taht_can_be_return_from_view }}`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, ExtractDay, TruncDate

device_record = Devc.objects.annotate(
    duration = Cast(
        ExtractDay(
            TruncDate(todays_date) - TruncDate(F('datebuy'))
        ),
        IntegerField()
    ).order_by('datebuy')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).